# Peepcode-git.pdf: Best strategy to keep a long standing feature branch in sync with main branch with rebase

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase, branching-and-merging

In the following documentation peepcode-git.pdf located at https://github.com/pluralsight/git-internals-pdf/releases, page 39 notes different use cases for rebase. Particularly this quote:

"If you get a huge project or idea – say refactoring the entire code base to the newest version of your framework or switching database vendors or something, you create a long-term branch, continuously rebase it to keep it in line with other development, and once every - thing is tested and ready, merge it in with your master."

The thing is the examples in the e-book goes over the ideas, the abstract applications for rebase but it doesn't provide concrete commands the user can reproduce examples against it. I can follow most of it except the "continuous rebase" part. Typically, when I have rebased I found it effective when:

- I am working on a branch of which I don't know how many commits I will make to get to the solution. Usually when I am experimenting with some code and it doesn't work, I put a note in the commit log to squash that commit since it offers no value. When I finally figure out the desired content state of my code, I rebase the branch to just the important commits, squashing out the others as stated. I then replay those changes via rebase onto the main branch.

If I am working on a long task however, I don't quite understand the idea of rebasing main onto my branch to stay in sync with it as it means that each commit in main will be replayed into a new commit onto my feature branch but it would  the exact same content state. This seems counter intuitive as valuable information is lost when the commit hash changes. Additionally, when it comes time to put feature branch work onto main, it would replay all its changes onto main including the duplicate commits (with different hashes) onto main. I think it would make more sense to continually merge main onto your local branch to keep it in sync with main and then when complete, rebase it onto main. This would help keep the merge-base to a newer point and reduce the number of commits that are replayed onto main. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple misunderstanding. The suggestion is not what you assumed:

> If I am working on a long task however, I don't quite understand the idea of rebasing main onto my branch to stay in sync...

Instead, you would regularly rebase **your** branch **onto** main. For example:

```
git switch my-long-lived-branch
git fetch
git rebase origin/main
```

Note it's possible that you could have conflicts when doing this type of rebase, if someone changed the same files on `main` that you changed on your branch.

You also mentioned:

> When I finally figure out the desired content state of my code, I rebase the branch to just the important commits, squashing out the others as stated.

That is another kind of rebase; an interactive rebase with the intent of fixing up your in-progress commits. You can do this separately against the merge-base (starting commit of your branch) anytime without having conflicts:

```
# if you know the commit ID of the parent of your first commit:
git rebase -i parent-ID-of-your-first-commit
# or if you have many commits and don't want to bother looking it up
git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD origin/main)
```

As for your suggestion about merging instead of rebasing:

> I think it would make more sense to continually merge main onto your local branch to keep it in sync with main and then when complete, rebase it onto main.

That would work fine, and so would the branch rebase, for bringing your branch up to date with the latest `origin/main`. I think it comes done personal preference. I personally prefer rebasing over merge in this situation, and if you're interactive rebasing anyway, you might as well do the branch rebase regularly as well.

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for your answer. Secondly, I still am not getting the documentation's suggestion. What you describe in your first paragraph is exactly how I thought the documentation suggested to do it. The issue I have with this suggestion is that the conflict must be fixed on each replayed commit... that is horrendous. Unless I am missing something, this doesn't sound like an inexpensive suggestion. I am erring on the side I am missing something and am trying to remain open minded.

Comment: I am wondering, if I followed your commands, would my log look something like (HEAD-> main, long_standing_feature_branch)? It would be local to my repo and that is key?

Comment: @LeanMan for simplicity, let's assume you have just one commit on your branch. Every day you could `git rebase origin/main` which would replay your one commit onto the latest `origin/main`. Each time you do it you would make your branch look as if you created your branch off of `origin/main` just "now". (Except that by default your original author date would not change, only the committer date would change to be "now".) The fact that this is local to you is key. You generally don't want to rewrite shared branches that others may already be working from.

Comment: @LeanMan Regarding conflicts over many commits; yeah, that is definitely possible with rebase. If you continually modified the same file over multiple commits, and then when you rebase onto the source branch and it was changed there as well, it can become quite tedious to keep dealing with the conflicts for multiple commits. Perhaps you could squash some of those commits first to have fewer conflicts, or there is a tool called [rerere](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) which can remember past conflict resolution for re-use. Or you could give up and merge in this case...

Comment: Haha... that is great clarification. Thank you. Yes, I think I probably ran into an issue where my branches were so diverged that I couldn't see the usefulness to it. But I think it makes sense. Doingo a bunch of small rebases over a long period time is better than doing one big rebase in a single massive way.